# Sampling the outcome of a function in R

Tags: r

I have a function which simulates the outcome of a particular card game, and returns a value denoting the outcome of the game. I want a concise syntax for sampling multiple plays of the game, and getting a vector containing the outcomes. This is what I want to be able to write:

```
sample(cardgame(params), iterations, replace=?)
```

which would ideally return a vector like (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...). The above syntax actually evaluates cardgame(params) once, and treats it as numerical parameter to sample. Is there a way to avoid creating the outcomes vector by hand with a for loop and multiple calls of the cardgame function? I ask, because being able to call sample() on user-created distributions would be very powerful.

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you found an acceptable answer on this thread? (check the green mark beneath users' votes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure whether this will help... have you checked out ?replicate ?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Mark T Patterson's answer...

```
> dummy_cardgame <- function(params) as.integer(runif(1) < params)
> replicate(10, dummy_cardgame(0.25))
 [1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```